# Prove that $f(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*(\frac{x}{2})^{2k})$ is absolute convergent and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I've got the Sequence of function $f(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*(\frac{x}{2})^{2k})$

I've to show that...

1. It's absolute convergent in $\mathbb{R}$
2. At least 2 times differentiable.

1) A sequence $\sum a_n$ converges absolute, when $\sum |a_n|$ converges. Meaning that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*(\frac{x}{2})^{2k}| = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{k!k!}*|(\frac{x}{2})^{2k}|) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{k!k!}*(\frac{x}{2})^{2k})$ should also converge.

But i don't know how to show it. It probably has something to do that factorials are growing faster than exponentials.
Any hints?

2) $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*(\frac{x}{2})^{2k}-\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*(\frac{x_0}{2})^{2k}}{x-x_0} = lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*((\frac{x^{2k}}{2^{2k}})-(\frac{x_0^{2k}}{2^{2k}}))}{x-x_0}=lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*\frac{1}{2^{2k}}(x^{2k}-x_0^{2k})}{x-x_0}=lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*\frac{1}{2^{2k}}(x-x_0)*(x^{k-1}+x^{2k-2}x_0+x^{2k-3}x_0^2+...+xx_0^{2k-2}+x_0^{2k-1})}{x-x_0}\\= lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*\frac{1}{2^{2k}}*(x^{2k-1}+x^{2k-2}x_0+x^{2k-3}x_0^2+...+xx_0^{2k-2}+x_0^{2k-1})\\ = \frac{(-1)^k}{k!k!}*\frac{1}{2^{2k}}*2k*x_0^{2k-1}$

The same is true for the second differentiation. Am i correct?

Thanks in advance for helpful advices.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)?

Comment: Am I allowed to use the ratio test here? I have a bit difficulties with the difference of normal sequences and function sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aleden has suggested the ratio test for 1)

$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|{\frac{1}{k!k!}*(\frac{x+1}{2})^{2k}}*k!k!*(\frac{2}{x})^{2k}|=lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|(\frac{(x+1)^{2k}}{x^{2k}})|=\infty $

Which is strange since i should show that is IS absolute convergent.

Comment: Ratio test: $~\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|{\frac{1}{(n+1)!(n+1)!}*(\frac{x}{2})^{2(n+1)}}*n!n!*(\frac{2}{x})^{2n}|=...~$

Comment: Why is the ratio test not dependent on x? Well... $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{x^2}{(n+1)(n+1)*4}|=0$

Comment: The question is not, why the ratio do not depend on $x$, the question should be which problem you have to understand it. *Answer:* Please distinguish between the variable $x$ (e.g. $x\in\mathbb{R}$) and the index $n$ (e.g. $n=0,1,2,3,4,5...$) . The ratio test is *defined* over $a_{n+1}/a_n$ so that only the variation of the index ($n\to n+1$) is relevant. That's a definition, there's nothing to interpret.

Comment: I see. It really is the definition - Cause only the Index of the sum matters. Thanks for that. Do you see any mistakes in my second question?

Comment: The calculations of point $2)$ are o.k. .